# What does this handwriting say for location of final destination?

Tags: united-states, palaeography, pennsylvania, manifest

I'm trying to read the handwriting on this ship manifest for Carl Guna, a coal miner arriving into New York on November 13, 1912:

[image]

See the one circled in red.  I've included all the entries on the page to help figure out.

Comment: I agree - it is Marianna, Pa. Perhaps you should self-answer this since you've answered it in the question.

Comment: @HarryVervet I've added an answer per your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As best as I can tell, the state is Pa, or Pennsylvania and the city is Marianna. I think it is PA from the other entries, such as Allegany, two above it. According to [Wikipedia, Marianna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marianna,_Pennsylvania) included coal mines open in 1912.